# Cannot open URL from terminal in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, macos-bigsur

The command `open https://google.com` does not seem to work from the terminal (zsh). Terminal becomes out of focus and WindowServer process seems to think, but no browser window is opened.

I tried `open -a Safari https://google.com` also.

Doing `open foo.txt` opens up text edit successfully.

Is this something with the strict permissions settings in macOS? Is there anything I need to change to be able to open a URL from the terminal?

Just checked on my Catalina machine, and I can open URLs.